# Find names based on max number dynamically in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data set like this:

Table A:

```
Date           PlaceName              Partner             Money
2021-03-26      SITE A               PARTNER A           100
2021-04-26      SITE B               PARTNER A           200
2021-03-26      SITE A               PARTNER B           0
2021-04-26      SITE B               PARTNER B           230
2021-04-26      SITE B               PARTNER B           230
2021-03-26      SITE A               PARTNER C           0
2021-04-26      SITE B               PARTNER C           230
2021-04-26      SITE B               PARTNER C           230
...
```

> What's the maximum number of Place on which a Partner has spent money and who are these Partners? Display only the Partners reaching this max number

I tried this:

```
select count(PlaceName) as num_of_sites, Partner
from (
    select distinct Place, Partner
    from TableA
    where Money > 0
) a
group by Partner
order by count(PlaceName) desc
```

But I feel like its not the right logic. What am I missing?

Comment: It's quite strange that all the partners have expent money in 2 places... maybe your sample data is not the best

Comment: @Carlos not true, only one partner in the sample spent money in 2 places, the other two spent money in one place at two times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no need for your subquery, [it works without it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/95acb/9):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.PlaceName) AS num_of_sites, a.Partner
FROM TableA a
WHERE a.Money > 0 
GROUP BY a.Partner
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT a.PlaceName) desc
```

but [it won't make any difference to have one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/95acb/10) because of how queries are optimized, so whichever is easier to read is best. With a sub query it looks like this:

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.PlaceName) AS num_of_sites, a.Partner
    FROM TableA a
    WHERE a.Money > 0 
    GROUP BY a.Partner) b
ORDER BY b.num_of_sites desc
```

If you [only want the name on the highest result(s)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/95acb/4) then you want to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES b.PARTNER 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.PlaceName) AS num_of_sites, a.Partner
    FROM TableA a
    WHERE a.Money > 0 
    GROUP BY a.Partner) b
ORDER BY b.num_of_sites desc
```

Comment: HAVING is used to filter groups, WHERE is used to filter rows which is what you would need here to exclude those rows. As posted this is invalid and won't run.

Comment: With your update this is better but it will return all partners, they want only those who meet the max number.

Comment: Also a "where num_of_sites = (select max(num_sites) from b)" is a good alternative for ties with , i think?

Comment: @SPishere not really, you can't reference b that way, results only flow up from subqueries, not up and then back into another one, so to do it that way you'd have to recreate b - and you can't just go `WHERE b.num_of_sites = MAX(b.num_of_sites)` because you can't have aggregate WHEREs without a grouping. There are other ways to do that, but they are all going to be as or more expensive than `TOP # WITH TIES`

Comment: Why do you think you are "recounting" `COUNT(DISTINCT a.PlaceName)`? Aggregates, and other expressions, are usually only calculated once

Comment: @Charlieface I'm not an expert on how it handles execution plans, I did take a look after your comment and my first two, and the query does get optimized into the exact same plan.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/252667 and others. It is true that *sometimes* a normal expression will not be recognized as having been calculated before, but an aggregate expression is almost always only calculated once. Obviously the expression has to be the same, so `COUNT(DISTINCT a.PlaceName + '')` wouldn't work

Comment: @Charlieface corrected